# how to load data from firestore to flutter app using stream Builder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm trying to load data from Firestore to my flutter app  , but I'm stuck in ' loading... ' text  ,  I feel I'm missing something !
Here is the code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kMainColor,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(kProductsCollection).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Product> products = [];
            for (var doc in snapshot.data.docs) {
              var data = doc.data();
              products.add(Product(
                  pPrice: data[kProductName],
                  pName: data[kProductPrice],
                  pDescription: data[kProductDescription],
                  pImage: data[kProductImage],
                  pCategory: data[kProductCategory]));
            }
            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: .8,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(products[index].pName),
              itemCount: products.length,
            );
          }
          else {
            // I'm stuck in here
            return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```